# Change default "admin:pass" in MongoExpress within Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongo-express

I'm running the MongoDB/MongoExpress stack via `docker compose up` as presented [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo):

```yaml
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

Everything works, but from the output of MongoExpress I can read

```
mongotest-mongo-express-1  | Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
mongotest-mongo-express-1  | Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
mongotest-mongo-express-1  | basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!
```

In fact, by connecting to `localhost:8081` I have to provide `admin` and `pass` as access credentials.

I would like to change this behaviour directly from the Dockerfile by setting the default username and password

Following [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express) documentation, I modified the `mongo-express` environment as follows:

```yaml
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN: false
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE: custom_db_name
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_USERNAME: custom_username
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_PASSWORD: custom_password
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

but nothing has changed, except for Mongo, which has gone from having three databases (`admin`, `config` and `local`) to only one (`test`).

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and I found a solution that works for me. I've checked the default [config file](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/blob/master/config.default.js) that is used by mongo-express.

Just set the `ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH` variable to `true`.

The `docker-compose.yml` file may look like the following:

```
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}:${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}@mongo:27017/

      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: $MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: $MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017

      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH: true
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: $ME_WEB_USERNAME
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: $ME_WEB_PASSWORD
```

I recommend using `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL`, this makes the connection much faster, but it works without this line.

Of course, you need to have a `.env` file with the following variables in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml`.

Sample `.env` file:

```
MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme

ME_WEB_USERNAME=user
ME_WEB_PASSWORD=qwerty
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't fix the problem when you are setting `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN` to `false`, but I assume you can just use your own `config.js` and pass it to docker.

Comment: Update: 
There is no need to use these variables: `ADMINUSERNAME`, `ADMINPASSWORD`, `SERVER`, `PORT`. In my case, this is unnecessary redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue about Docker, but let me try to explain the user management in MongoDB.

A user is scoped to a database, i.e. you can define the database where the user is created, for example:

```
use products
db.createUser( { 
   user: "custom_username",
   pwd: "secret"
   roles: [ 
      { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" },
      "readWrite"
   ] 
})
```

or you can also write

```
db.getSiblingDB("products").createUser(...
```

However, usually users are created in `admin` database, honestly I don't know any reason why user should be created somewhere else.

The `admin` database is built-in database. Apart from user authentication and authorization data it also includes [Roles](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/built-in-roles/#built-in-roles) for administering the whole system rather than just a single database. These roles are mainly related to replica set and sharded cluster administrative functions.

Roles which are created in **other** database than `admin` can only include privileges that apply to its database and can only inherit from other roles in its database.

A role created in the `admin` database can include privileges that apply to **any** database or to the cluster resource, and can inherit from roles in other databases as well as the `admin` database.

Try `db.getUsers()` to see where users are created and which roles thy got granted.